# PHP: How to put a variable in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

Just a quick newbie PHP syntax question.

I have a variable, let's call it `$tabs` which always contains a string of numbers separated by commas, like so: `24,35,43,21`

I also have a variable that's an array:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array(27,19,29), 'order' => 'ASC');
```

That's of course WordPress. What I need to do, is place the content of the `$tabs` variable (numbers) where the numbers inside the array are. I'm rather new to PHP, only understand how to modify some things, but this I can't figure out, no idea how the syntax for it should go.

Anyone able to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$args['post__in'] = array_merge($args['post__in'], explode(',', $tabs));
```

Let's explain what I did so you may pick up a thing or two:

1. `explode(',', $tabs)` splits a string into pieces at a separator and puts that pieces in an array.
2. `array_merge($arr1, $arr2)` will merge the two arrays.
3. `$args['post__in']` will access an array element specified by a key.

Note that array_merge, in this case, will just append the values and you may end up with duplicate numbers. To get rid of duplicates just wrap the merge in `array_unique`. Like so:

```
$args['post__in'] = array_unique(array_merge($args['post__in'], explode(',', $tabs)));
```

And of course, the trivial case when you just want to replace those numbers with brand new ones is

```
$args['post__in'] = explode(`,`, $tabs);
```

Comment: +1 if he wants to append. Rather ambiguous if he wants to append or replace. (and explaining)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot. First time someone actually explained the solution so I can learn from it. @Jason She ;)

Answer (score 2):

`$args['post__in'] = explode(",",$tabs);`