# PHP - strange syntax errors with brackets inside Class array

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, brackets

I have a simple code like so :

```
        class o99_custom_fields {
            /**
            * @var  string  $prefix  The prefix for storing custom fields in the postmeta table
            */
            var $prefix = 'o99_';
            /**
            * @var  array  $customFields  Defines the custom fields available
            */
            var $customFields = array(

                array(
                    "name"          => "some_name",
                    "title"         => "some Title",
                    "description"   => "Some Desctiption Text",
                    "type"          => "k_upload",
                    "scope"         =>  array( "post" ),
                    "capability"    => "edit_post"
                ),

                array(
                    "name"          => "some_name2",
                    "title"         => "some Title",
                    "description"   => "Some Desctiption Text",
                    "type"          => "k_upload",
                    "scope"         =>  array( "post" ),
                    "capability"    => "edit_post"
                ),

                array(
                    "name"          => "some_name3",
                    "title"         => "some Title",
                    "description"   => "",
                    "type"          => "k_textarea",
                    "scope"         =>  array( "post" ),
                    "capability"    => "edit_post"
                ),
            );
... more functions and more code ...
    } // End Class
```

And everything seems ok,

The problem begins when I am trying to change some array values , and put them inside Brackets `()`

for example :

```
array(
                "name"          => "some_name",
                "title"         => __("some Title","text_domain"),// ERROR OCCUR
                "description"   => "Some Desctiption Text",
                "type"          => "k_upload",
                "scope"         =>  array( "post" ),
                "capability"    => "edit_post"
            ),
```

The Error message is :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in E:\my_path\myfile.php on line 18
```

Note that it is not related to the function `__()` ( [standard wordpress translation function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) ) and the error is not function related , but `SYNTAX`. ( I have used this function hundreds of times in the past , without any problems - and in this case , also `_x()`  and `_e()` fail on the same syntax errors .. )

All my brackets are closed , I have checked and re checked , and Unless I am totally blind , I would say that it is ok , but I still getting this error , no matter where I put the brackets inside this class .

Another example : this will also fail with the same error :

```
class o99_custom_fields {
                /**
                * @var  string  $prefix  The prefix for storing custom fields in the postmeta table
                */
                var $prefix = 'o99_';
                /**
                * @var  array  $customFields  Defines the custom fields available
                */
                var $dummy_strings = array (
__('x1','text_domain'),
__('x2','text_domain'),
);

    ... more functions and more code ...
        } // End Class
```

Again, the error appears to be `SYNTAX` related , even though all my brackets are closed .
I have also checked the file for proper php opening and closing tags , and even charset and encoding ( UTF-8 without BOM )

I have  never encountered such a problem before - so any help / hint / insight would be greatly appreciated ..

EDIT I :

After those arrays, comes the constructors ..

```
/**
* PHP 4 Compatible Constructor
*/
function o99_custom_fields() { $this->__construct(); }
/**
* PHP 5 Constructor
*/

function __construct() {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( &$this, 'createCustomFields' ) );
    add_action( 'save_post', array( &$this, 'saveCustomFields' ) );
}
```

Comment: well you're completely right, and that's odd to have :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is because you can't initialize class properties by calling other functions.

Initializing a property to a default value like this:

```
class SomeClass{
...
private $myProp0 = array(); //OK
private $myProp1 = array('foo' => 'bar', 'foooo' => 'baaar'); //OK
private $myProp2 = null; //OK
private $myProp3 = 10; //OK
private $myProp4 = "something"; //OK
private $myProp5 = __('translate me') // NOT OK
...
}
```

To initialize your property with some other value (e.g. by calling some other function) you must set it in the constructor of your class.

Something like this should work:

```
function someFunction($x, $y){
    return "mouahahaha";
}

class SomeClass{
    private $something = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->something = array(
            'somekey1' => 'foobar',
            'somekey2' => someFunction("foo", "bar"),
        );
    }
}
```

In other words ,  You need to move your array initialization from the class body to a constructor.

Putting that example to your own code :

```
class o99_custom_fields {
        /**
        * @var  string  $prefix  The prefix for storing custom fields in the postmeta table
        */
        var $prefix = 'o99_';
        /**
        * @var  array  $customFields  Defines the custom fields available
        */
         private $customFields = array();
        /**
        * PHP 4 Compatible Constructor
        */
        function o99_custom_fields() { $this->__construct(); }
        /**
        * PHP 5 Constructor
        */

        public function __construct() {

         $this->customFields =  array(

            array(
            "name"          => "some_name",
            "title"         => __("some Title","text_domain"),// NO ERROR NOW
            "description"   => "Some Desctiption Text",
            "type"          => "k_upload",
            "scope"         =>  array( "post" ),
            "capability"    => "edit_post"
        ),
       );
       // Do your other construct things 
     } // END __construct
```

Comment: see the comment for Damien Pirsy. the function `__()` is already declared and available . And also- all I get is a SYNTAX error ( I also do not see from your example how can I resolve it , even if I think you are right in direction. Just adding public to my construct does not help and the error persist )

Comment: Problem is that you can't initialise **class properties** using values that are not constants or "constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated"

Comment: Then how to do that right ? ( please keep in mind that I am quit a newbie with classes and PHP ..) I also tried the methods described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018413/php-how-to-put-a-variable-in-an-array?rq=1 ( anonymous functions and callback )

Comment: Look at my updated answer. You need to move your array initialization from the class body to a constructor.

Comment: Your last remark is the explanation I was looking for. It does work now and problem solved .. The problems is my lack of knowledge in OOP with PHP.. But explaining in lame man's terms (or in this case girls´s ) does help :-) Until that comment , I did not really understood what practical steps should be taken. The explanation of the problem was given, but not the solution ..

Comment: Thanks again. I still do not understand why it is classified and presented as a `syntax` error ..

Comment: Yes, the error description is not really helpful in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed now that your problematic array is a class property; the error it's not really helping here, but reading on the manual on [class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> [...]This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

i.e., the __() function falls into this scenario. In fact, if it were a normal array definition, it wouldn't cast errors, see this [ideone](http://ideone.com/poNyw4)

```
function __($param1,$param2){}

$customFields = array(
   array(
     "name" => "some_name",
      "title" => __("some Title","text_domain"),// ERROR OCCUR
      "description" => "Some Desctiption Text",
      "type" => "k_upload",
      "scope" => array( "post" ),
      "capability" => "edit_post"
    ),
);
```

Use a constructor to inizialize a property; also, the keyword `var` should be subsituted with the explicit visibility keyword (here, `public`)

Comment: Indeed I suspected it has something to do with the fact it being a class - but I still do not really understand . 1 - The __() function is already declared and available 2. - I have the construct at class ( See EDIT I ) and 3 . Why a syntax Error ?